# Django cassandra search engine

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, solr, cassandra

Anyone tried integrating any search engines such as elasticsearch or solr integrated with Cassandra using django haystack, please suggest if you tried any for your Django Cassandra project.

Comment: I could read that Solr and Cassandra are well coupled, than elastic search, will this bring any advantage